# Where do data mining and computer vision converge?

Tags: data-mining

I am traditionally a computer vision guy, and have started doing some self-learning in data mining.  I'm having a hard time finding places where these 2 fields converge, as I'd like to get a self-study project that relates the two fields.

where are these areas two used together?

Comment: If by *data mining* you mean something closer to *machine learning*, then you might look at Sebastian Thrun (used to be at CMU; now at Stanford and Google, I think) and collaborators designing self-driving cars (I think they're now at least partly funded by Google, but it started with some DARPA challenges) and Andrew Ng doing other robotics tasks incorporating computer vision. He also has a nice example of inferring depth (i.e., third dimensional) from 2D still images. There is also a tremendous amount of research by many people in scene recognition from still images.

Comment: I do know of lots of machine learning projects and research going on, but I am thinking moreso towards data *mining*, and data driven approaches

Comment: There is also some interesting work of Geoffrey Hinton on automated "natural" image generation via things like Restricted Boltzmann Machines.

Comment: @cardinal: I'd make this an answer. Machine learning is the common thread. socks: do you do computer vision in the abstract, or as a part of robotics? Kalman/particle filters -> time series.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen some work in which researchers are able to harness the availability of large amounts of image data from the web to perform complex tasks (e.g. similarity search).

Two excellent examples I can think of are [this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/tmp/tiny.pdf) and the work by [James Hays](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~hays/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are various places. For example, indexing image data is a natural source of convergence between data mining and computer vision. In order to cluster images, you will probably want to have a tight interplay of computer vision and data mining, too.

Or for example [Robust Segmentation of Relevant Regions in Low Depth of Field Images](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/cms/Publications/Robust_Segmentation_of_Relevant_Regions_in_Low_Depth_of_Field_Images), an image segmentation method that is in fact based on DBSCAN clustering. I bet you can come up with many such examples when you look around. Say: aligning a stack of panorama images requires actually some kind of data mining, too. At least when you have a few thousand SIFT keypoints to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The most prominent example is the [HMAX](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/spring10/slides/class15-visualneuroscience/class15-hmax.pdf) model. The model uses a series of layers to produce a single vector feature set that is composted of the data needed to classify objects using machine learning. In order to achieve in-variance (Rotation, Size, Scale) in this model the developer needs to have many pictures of the same thing or person which can be used to train a classifier.

When researchers are attempting to find better ways of creating or reading these features, that's where computer vision meets data mining.